# I am using pnp peoplepicker in spfx and I want to clear the selected value by user on this people picker by code

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnp, react

Here is the people picker I am using within my component's Render:

```
<PeoplePicker context={this.props.context} titleText="" personSelectionLimit={1} groupName={""} showtooltip={true}  selectedItems={this._employeeName} showHiddenInUI={false} principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]} resolveDelay={1000} ensureUser={true} disabled={false} defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.userEmail ? this.state.userEmail : []} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a `selectedUsers` value to your state, which you could set in your constructor's state initialization to `this._employeeName`, then you would change the selectedItems attribute in your PeoplePicker to `selectedItems={this.state.selectedUsers}`

At that point you would be able to use whatever logic you need within your component to call `this.setState({selectedUsers: null})`

Comment: I am using to selectedItems={this._employeeName} to get user profile properties of employee on resolve that is the problem I cannot change that

Comment: If you cannot change what `selectedItems` is bound to, then I think you are stuck.  If you bind to a private variable instead of a state value, you'd have to completely re-instantiate the component to change the bound value.

Answer (score 0):

It should work to set this._employeeName to null and to reset user state you are using for defaultSelectedUsers this.state.userMail to [].
By setting the state you trigger a rerendering while you deleted the current selected information by setting _employeeName to null or undefined

Comment: I am using  this.setState({userEmail : ' ',}); 
      this._employeeName(this.state.userEmail);

Comment: Does this work or is this the way you go but doesn't work? 

It  could be to fast, so the second call will use old state values. If you want to work that way use setTimeout --->    this.setState({userEmail : ' '});setTimeout(() => this._employeeName(this.state.userEmail), 50);

Comment: I was trying without settimeout but even after using settimeout it is not working